# Shall I close or even delete question based on misunderstanding?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, deleted-questions

My very own, recently asked question ([this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/386900/46952)) is based on a misunderstanding / problems with memory.

*I am asking why my Mail app on my old iPad isn't receiving any messages?*

After reviewing my other, much older question ([this one](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/40664/21486)) and my own blog post, written after that old question ([here](http://onezeronull.com/2013/02/22/getting-icloud-me-com-emails-to-gmail/)) I managed to recall that I have setup a permanent messages forward with original message deletion. And it turned out that this is the sole cause for not seeing any messages in my Mail app's Inbox (but still seeing them in Sent box).

What should I do in this case:

- delete question,
- close question (with some comment) or
- add my own answer to double check (for future reader / reference) if message forward isn't enabled on the account?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m a big fan of there’s no harm in a wrong answer or even a question that can be edited. If the question is something you didn’t realize, answering how you discovered the actual answer can be super helpful.

Same with wrong answers, everyone can read things differently or not realize some key item and wrong answers actually tech and document that better than correct answers when both exist with good comments.

Why not self answer and then if it’s getting bad votes, we can help edit and maybe correct things?

Deletion is good if there’s little chance you can salvage it. I would start with the best option. Make an answer and tick the check as answered and wait.

Comment: Thank you, [done](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/387576/46952).

Comment: Looks great, thank you so much for helping the site work @trejder